# Automatic test measuring dissimilarity between two time series

Tags: distributions, time-series, computational-statistics, cross-correlation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two time series, series1 and series2. My aim is to find **how much Series2 is different from Series1, automatically/quantitatively**.
Image can be seen in its original size by [clicking here](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/3401/image001eg.gif).
[image]

Series1 is the expected result.
Series2 is the test/incoming series.

I am providing a histogram plot, where Series2 is represented in dark brown colour. You can also note in the x-axis between 221 and 353 there is a significant variation. ie Series2 is less than Series1. I am coding using C++.

I think, crosscorrelation will help, but produces a value based on similarity rather than dissimilarity. I see people talk about Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test. Is this the test which i should be performing?

UPDATE 1: I am trying to perform a template matching. I have divided my template image in to 8x8 blocks as well as my incoming test image. I am trying to compare one block in template image with the same block(based on the spatial pixel positions) in the test image. I calculate the intensity sum within each block. I obtain series1 for the Template image and have Series2 for the test image.

Comment: I would suggest you to work on clarity of the question; this helps in getting answers.

Comment: @mbq, i have updated to my post

Answer (score 3):

There are many different distance measures.  For starters, there's always the correlation.

You can look at the [mean square error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).  In R, you can see the algorithm for time series in Rob Hyndman's [ftsa](http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/ftsa/) package (see the `error` function).

See [Liao (2005)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.115.6594) for a nice short survey of time series similarity measures, including euclidean distance, root mean square distance, mikowski distance, pearson's correlation, dynamic time warping distance, kullback-liebler disance, symmetric Chernoff information divergence, and cross-correlation.

- T. Warren Liao, ["Clustering of time series data—a survey"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.115.6594) Pattern Recognition, 2005

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will test this approach and will update. Also, do you think, i can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test in my case. Please see the plot, http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/9645/25971376.gif